# How to check a path is a file or folder in PHP

Tags: php, file, scandir

I use scandir() to search files recursively. But if the file path directs to a file not a folder, there will be a warning. How can I check the path whether it directs a file or folder?

```
enter code here
<?php

$path = "C:\\test_folder\\folder2\\folder4";
$sub_folder = scandir($path);
$num = count($sub_folder);
for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
{
...//if $sub_folder[$i] is a file but a folder, there will be a warning.
       How can I check $sub_folder[$i] before use it?




}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: a really quick google gives the answer in the php manual, bool is_dir ( string $filename )

Comment: [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look into is_dir() and is_file()

```
<?php

$path = "C:\\test_folder\\folder2\\folder4";
$sub_folder = scandir($path);
$num = count($sub_folder);
for ($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    if(is_file($path.'\\'.$sub_folder[$i])){
        echo 'Warning';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used is_dir() and is_file() before, but just used $sub_folder[$i] as the argument by mistake and didn't get the result I want.

Answer (score 4):

[is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) should tell you if a path is a directory or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether if the variable has file extension or not.

This "if" will gets files only :

```
if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
```

and this "if" will gets directories only:

```
if (!pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) ([class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php))

```
$path = 'your path';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(realpath($path));
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isFile()) {
        // it's a file
    }
}
```

Also, you may check [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) and [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).