# How to test for a folder with RecursiveTreeIterator

Tags: php

I have tried question [How to check a path is a file or folder in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903719/how-to-check-a-path-is-a-file-or-folder-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But i could only get the answers to output the first level directories.

I want to search dirs and subdirs and if the result is a folder, do some code. Also if the result is a file, do some code. I also want to be able to use the directory path too so e.g. if a directory is folder1/folder2/folder3, i want to be able to use that path as a variable that i can later place it in mysql. I dont need the mysql code, just being able to assign the path in a variable will do. Here is my code, which outputs nothing:

```
$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new     RecursiveDirectoryIterator("path", RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) ;
foreach($it as $path) {if(is_dir($path)) {echo $path;}}
```

When removing the if statement and just echoing the path the program works like a charm outputting all of the directories and subfolders and files. But when I add the if statement it outputs nothing. How can these things be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual path is in the key value of the iteration, so your foreach should look like e.g. `foreach ($it as $path => $branch)`. The TreeIterator actually creates a tree-like string if you properly look at it and add a line break after the echo =)

Comment: So the path is the key and the branch is the value?

Comment: yes exactly. so e.g. if you want to echo every directory with the pretty formatting, you check is_dir($key) and echo $value

Comment: That is a great answer. Thanks matey,  its working just fine.

Comment: I ticked your answer but i dont know is that registers as me saying that that's the answer. Is that all I need to do to have yours as the answer? Because i want to add more code in another answer below so people can see the full answer with path to variable incl etc.

Comment: yup, that should be enough =)